# Database insert performance

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, sqlite

We are planning to implement a system for logging a high frequency of market ticks into a DB for further analysis. To simply get a little what kind of storage performance we can get on the different DB solutions I created a little application for inserting a basic row of tick information. When running the same code on a couple of different DBs we got some interesting results.

The data being inserted is very simple like follows :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[price](
    [product_code] [char](15) NULL,
    [market_code] [char](10) NULL,
    [currency] [nchar](6) NULL,
    [timestamp] [datetime] NULL,
    [value] [float] NULL,
    [price_type] [char](4) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**Microsoft SQL Server :**

Total test time : 32 seconds. 3,099 prices per second.

**MySQL Server :**

Total test time : 18 seconds. 5,349 prices per second.

**MongoDB Server :**

Total test time : 3 seconds. 25,555 prices per second.

The purpose of this testing is simply to get a little indication of what kind of "raw performance" can be expected of the systems in the bottom. When actually implementing a solution we would of course do buffering, bulk inserts etc.

We only care about the speed of the inserts, as the querying is done "offline" later.

Does anyone have any suggestions for other databases that could fit? I will be trying with HDF5 and MonetDB later tonight too. Its required to have multi client access.

Thanks for any suggestions!

UPDATED :

Sorry, but i did a major edit of my question before positing, and it seems i left out the server versions and some details of the hardware. All tests were on an 8 core server with 12GB RAM running Windows 2008 x64.

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Enterprise x64.
MySQL 5.1.44 running as InnoDB table.
MongoDB 1.2.4 x64

The current test is a simple loop of row inserts into the DBs with real historic data from NASDAQ compiled in a CSV file already imported to memory. The code was in C# NET4 x64.

The MS SQL and MySQL servers were "tuned" to perfect settings, while the MongoDB was just set up with defaults. The SQL tables are set up with no indices, as the purpose of the DB is simple as a staging ground before being transfered into the main analysis system.

Many suggested Bulk inserts, however its a difficult way of doing it as we have several clients pushing single ticks into the DB independently from live streams. To allow for such methods, we would have to expand the layer in front of the DB beyond what we have a chance to test for right now. However I imagine something will have to be done for the final architecture, as the numbers we are getting from everything except the MongoDB is not enough to handle the number of inputs needed.

UPDATE 2: SSD drives are indeed great for just this, and we are using this ourselves. However the final product will be installed at a few different customers which all provide their own iron.. and getting servers from the IT department with SSD is still hard... :(

UPDATE 3:

I tried the BulkCopy approach suggested. Performance for the same loop as the others, but first into a DataTable and then BulkInsert into the SQL Server resulted in the following :

**Microsoft SQL Server (Bulk) :**

Total test time : 2 seconds. 39401 prices per second.

Comment: You should  test with buffering and bulk inserts as well. Also make sure you use the same indices and constraints as the real system will, and do the test with a Db that is reasonably filled.

Comment: Remember also that the hardware matters greatly here, for example some high-end SSD drives are going to give tremendously better performance, so look at where you spend your money to see how much it matters.

Comment: Are you testing them on same machine? are you using the sql server express edition ?

Comment: It makes more sense to discuss mySQL benchmarks when you disclose which storage engine (innoDB, MyIsam, etc) you used.  Also, you didn't disclose what kind of key you need to use.  Do your rows have unique identifiers?  Does a new row sometimes replace an old row?  How are you going to retrieve the data?  If the answer is "always sequentially" you end up with a very different database setup than if you need to retreive "by market code and timestamp range."

Comment: TiTaN, it was SQL Server 2008 Enterprise x64.

Answer (score 5):

I can only really comment on sql-server, but there are some things to try:

- command batching (i.e. do multiple `INSERT` in a single hit to the db)
- bulk insert (via [`SqlBulkCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx))

either should give *significant* improvements on single-row inserts (the latter being fastest)

Comment: +1 - I recently blogged a performance comparison using SqlBulkCopy vs. batched updates using SqlDataAdapter here: http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2010/02/sqlbulkcopy-bulk-load-to-sql-server.html

Result being 0.8229s to insert 100,000 records on my home PC.

Comment: Indeed very interesting. But SqlBulkCopy has the problem of requiring exclusive access to the table when doing the insert, no?

Comment: @Erik - it depends what you choose for the lock mode. "table" is fastest but exclusive. There are more granular options.

Comment: while this question is old the issue of performance is of constant interest and since I don't see it here I thought I should post my recent experience with SQL Server. I tried single insert, multiple insert, and sqlbulkCopy. Each was faster then the other, none fast enough for my requirement of importing between 6-8 million records. The fastest of those took too long to wait. Programmatically calling a stored procedure to bulk-import 3 pre-parsed tab delimited files (< 1 min for parsing/writing all 3 logs) the entire record-set in 3 localized files is being imported in ~4 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

> The purpose of this testing is simply
>   to get a little indication of what
>   kind of "raw performance" can be
>   expected of the systems in the bottom.
>   When actually implementing a solution
>   we would of course do buffering, bulk
>   inserts etc.

You could at least share the details of your tests. Omitting such crucial information as **what MySQL engine** you try is unpardonable. And the "raw performance" of a non-batched insert on a buffer-pooled based DB (like SQL Server or InnoDB) is non-sense, is like measuring the "raw performance" of a Ferrari in first-gear and then publishing that "it only goes to 50mph".

But anyway, if you want a highly scalable write optimized DB, look at [Cassandra](http://incubator.apache.org/cassandra/) from Apache Incubation. [The rumor mill says Twitter will adopt it soon](http://www.informationweek.com/news/software/open_source/showArticle.jhtml?articleID=223100894).

Answer (score 2):

How do these compare to simply logging to a flat file in the file system?  If querying is done later, I'm not sure why you are bringing the data into a relational database at this time.  Is there a need for transactions or multiple access to the database at all during this recording stage?

Comment: Exactly, if query is done later, no one beats the performance of simply appending to a text file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want insert-only operations, you can get more out of mysql by using [Archive engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/archive-storage-engine.html) and `INSERT DELAYED`.

Otherwise, try any of the local-storage KV engines: BDB, QDBM, Tokyo Cabinet, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to optimize performance and different databases handle data very different as well. SQL Server for example is protecting your data, it has to be sure the data is valid and on disk before it lets you know the insert has been succesfull. MySQL nor MongoDB is doing that, so they can be faster. So, what are you looking for? A RDBMS or some storage where you can afford it to loose some data?

Answer (score 0):

BerkeleyDB might be worth a look if your data can be represented as key/value pairs (as if in a PERL hash or similar data structure).  It's fast, multiclient, and transaction-safe, even if it is not the latest wizbang thing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you test with several application instances connected the the Database Server and inserting data at the same time or just one application?

I think you should be testing with multiple instances especially for bulk insertion and see what configuration works for you. Different transaction isolation modes can greatly affect the performance for concurrent access (especially write access). SQL Server for example, I found that **lower** isolation mode than ReadCommitted should be used for highly concurrent environment or you will find lot of cases of timeout. This should of course be used when the risk of dirty read is not a concern (which fit your case judging from your description).

PS: Forgive me if I'm stating the obvious here.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider checking MySQL 5.5 release candidate as well. Oracle guys made significant improvements in this version, specially for windows release. Up to 1,500 percent performance gains for Read/Write operations, and up to 500 percent gain for Read Only. You can refer to this link for more info:

http://www.mysql.com/news-and-events/generate-article.php?id=2010_04